# ErrorMessage and ValidationSummary in asp.net (web forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i'm beginning with web forms in asp.net and i just want a simple example of how can i show a error message on my aspx page. The intention, is to make run as follows:

- The user fill 2 fields
- User submit the form
- The 2 fields are compared on the server
- If the two aren't equals, show the same page with the classical red text on the side of the field

It's really a very simple situation, but it's just to know how to work properly with the ErrorMessage and ValidationSummary...

I'm very grateful for any help!

P.S.: I'm using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/aspnetvalidation.aspx

cheers

Comment: This will help me a lot =) Thank you!